# Access the Apps available in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi i would like to access the apps which are available in iphone means downloaded apps and inbuild apps.But here issue is if i access any app which is available in iphone using [[UIapplication sharedapplication]openurl:[NSURl url urlwithstring:@"http://www.skype.com"]] like this i can able to access that iphone app succesfully but if i want to come back to my app i did not find any way only i have to hit homebutton. So is there anyway to come back to my app at any point of time. if anyone know please let me know. Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there anyway to come back to my app at any point of time.

Not unless the other app supports returning back to the calling app (by responding to a special specifier in the URL, for example).

Note that there is also `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` which will tell you if a particular URL scheme is supported. This is useful to check whether a particular app is installed without attempting to launch it.

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply in my app the code which i used for calling the app available in phone. in that header file i found this method - (BOOL)canOpenKakaoLink; is this will  be useful for come back to our app without quiting the app?

Comment: How should I know what one of your custom methods does?

Answer (score 0):

That is default behavior of the iOS application. Once your application is in background there is no way to come back to your application `programatically`.

User has to manually open your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to some other apps on the phone using the URL method, however **you cannot return to your app**.

Once you navigate to the other app, it takes over and your app is no longer running.  Therefore, the other app would need to navigate back to you.  That obviously is not possible, unless you had access to the code of the other app.